# Company completion in Elixir with lsp-mode/eglot not working as expected

Tags: completion, company-mode

I’ve got `elixir-mode` and `lsp-mode` (before I was using `eglot` but the same problem persisted) configured in my emacs.d and it mostly works. One thing I can’t figure out though is how to work with the code completion (via company) in elixir code.

Say I type `defm` at this point I get the completion options pop up. I select `defmodule` with `enter` and then `tab` to expand. The code expands to:

```
defmodule $1 do
        $0
end
```

However the cursor (point) moves to the end of `end`. I get no opportunity to specify the module name and also complete the module body.

What I was expecting was, upon pressing tab, the code will expand as it does now but the cursor (point) should be placed at `$1` where I can type the module name, then another `tab` will move cursor (point) to `$0` for the content of the module body in that order.

When I disable `lsp-mode` and use only `elixir-mode` I get the expected behaviour were selecting d`efmodule` from the completion list places the cursor (point) between `defmodule` and ``do where I get to type the module name then another tab places the cursor inside the module body.

How can I get the experience I just described with `lsp-mode` and elixir? I have included below a stripped down version of my config in case someone will like to try is recreate what I've described.

```
;; Produce backtraces when errors occur
;;(setq debug-on-error t)
(setq message-log-max 10000)


;; Add aditional load paths
;;(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "lisp" user-emacs-directory))
;;(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "site-lisp" user-emacs-directory))

(defconst my-savefile-dir (expand-file-name "savefile" user-emacs-directory))


;; create the savefile dir if it doesn't exist
(unless (file-exists-p my-savefile-dir)
  (make-directory my-savefile-dir))

(defconst *is-a-mac* (eq system-type 'darwin))


;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Adjust garbage collection thresholds during startup, and thereafter
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(let ((normal-gc-cons-threshold (* 20 1024 1024))
      (init-gc-cons-threshold (* 128 1024 1024)))
  (setq gc-cons-threshold init-gc-cons-threshold)
  (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
            (lambda () (setq gc-cons-threshold normal-gc-cons-threshold))))

(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))

;; Package configs
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq package-archives '(("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)


;; bootstrap `use-package`
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;; From use-package README
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))

;; To aid benchmarking
(setq use-package-verbose t)

(unless (fboundp 'helm-mode)
  (ido-mode t)
  (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t))



(autoload 'zap-up-to-char "misc"
  "Kill up to, but not including ARGth occurrence of CHAR." t)

(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'forward)

(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'zap-up-to-char)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward-regexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") 'isearch-backward-regexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") 'isearch-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'isearch-backward)

(show-paren-mode 1)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t
      apropos-do-all t
      mouse-yank-at-point t
      require-final-newline t
      visible-bell t
      load-prefer-newer t
      ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain
      save-place-file (concat user-emacs-directory "places")
      backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,(concat user-emacs-directory
                                               "backups"))))


(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :if (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  :ensure t
  :init (setq-default exec-path-from-shell-arguments nil)
  :config
  (progn
    (dolist (var '("SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "SSH_AGENT_PID" "GPG_AGENT_INFO" "LANG" "LC_CTYPE" "WORKON_HOME"))
      (add-to-list 'exec-path-from-shell-variables var))
    (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)))


;; Flycheck
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq flycheck-display-errors-function #'flycheck-display-error-messages-unless-error-list)
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))

;; Company
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :hook (after-init . global-company-mode)
  :init
  (setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
  (setq company-dabbrev-downcase 0)
  (setq company-idle-delay 0)
  (setq company-require-match 'never)
  (setq company-show-numbers t)
  (setq-default company-dabbrev-other-buffers 'all
                company-tooltip-align-annotations t)
  (setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
  :config
  (define-key company-mode-map (kbd "M-/") 'company-complete)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") 'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") 'company-select-previous))


;; Suspend page-break-lines-mode while company menu is active
;; (see https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/416)

(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (with-eval-after-load 'page-break-lines
    (defvar-local sanityinc/page-break-lines-on-p nil)

    (defun sanityinc/page-break-lines-disable (&rest ignore)
      (when (setq sanityinc/page-break-lines-on-p (bound-and-true-p page-break-lines-mode))
        (page-break-lines-mode -1)))

    (defun sanityinc/page-break-lines-maybe-reenable (&rest ignore)
      (when sanityinc/page-break-lines-on-p
        (page-break-lines-mode 1)))

    (add-hook 'company-completion-started-hook 'sanityinc/page-break-lines-disable)
    (add-hook 'company-after-completion-hook 'sanityinc/page-break-lines-maybe-reenable)))

;; LSP
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands lsp
  :hook ((elixir-mode . lsp))
  :init
  (setq lsp-prefer-flymake nil)
  (setq lsp-enable-completion-at-point t)
  (setq lsp-enable-xref t)
  :config
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/napo/github/elixir-ls/release")) ;; Uncomment for lsp-mode

(use-package lsp-ui
  :after (lsp-mode)
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :ensure t
  :init
  ;;(setq lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil)
  ;;(setq lsp-ui-sideline-ignore-duplicate t)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-max-width 50)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-max-hight 20)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-include-signature t)
  (setq lsp-ui-peek-always-show t)
  :commands lsp-ui-mode)

(use-package company-lsp
  :after (company lsp-mode)
  :ensure t
  :commands company-lsp
  :init
  (push 'company-lsp company-backends))


;; Elxir
(use-package elixir-mode
  :after (company lsp-mode)
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;; Create a buffer-local hook to run elixir-format on save, only when we enable elixir-mode.
  (add-hook 'elixir-mode-hook
            (lambda () (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'elixir-format nil t))))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install yasnippet https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet . lsp-mode is using it to expand the completion templates.